# How to install Java 6 on Mac OSX 10.75

Tags: java

I am no longer finding Java 6 on my Mac. I suspect when I upgraded to OSX 7.5 it upgraded my Java.

I am running an open source project that must be in Java 6. I can only find Java 6 for OSX 6

Is there any way to downgrade Java? I would hate to have to downgrade OSX just for this project.

Comment: This question has already been answered. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594864/how-to-revert-to-java-1-6-on-mac-os-x-10-7-5?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: The answer there is not complete. Yes, you can build to an earlier target, but if your source contains Java 7 API's, it will still not run on Java 6. I am really asking for a new Java 6 installation download for OSX 7.5

Comment: More resources: http://superuser.com/questions/296989/where-to-download-jdk-1-6-for-os-x and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577014/how-install-a-specific-jdk-on-mac-os-x