# how to install a java 1.6 jdk on my maverick mac

Tags: macos, mac, install, java

I have jsd 1.7 on my machine and I want to install 1.6 as well

I couldn't find a way to do so.

Anybody know?

Comment: This question has been asked a million times: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87374/how-to-install-java-6-on-mac-osx-10-75, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594864/how-to-revert-to-java-1-6-on-mac-os-x-10-7-5, http://superuser.com/questions/296989/where-to-download-jdk-1-6-for-os-x, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577014/how-install-a-specific-jdk-on-mac-os-x

Comment: that's the thing. all the download link that used to java 6, now lead to the latests release aka java 7

Comment: here: i cannot find it even here: https://developer.apple.com/search/index.php?q=java%2010.6

Comment: this has answered my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13594864/how-to-revert-to-java-1-6-on-mac-os-x-10-7-5?answertab=active#tab-top